# 'My' position in a leaderboard

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation where I need to retrieve the position of the current user in a regional leaderboard.

My tables look something like this:

```
Users
id | city | ...
```

```
Collected_Items
id | user_id | value | ...
```

```
Achievements
id | user_id | value | ...
```

So simply put, I'd like to retrieve the position in the leaderboard and the sum of the `value` of each `collected_item` as well as the sum of the `value` each `achievement`. Equal total values can be either ranked equally or based on the timestamp of collection (first to collect wins)

I have this so far: (adapted from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072364/1238887))

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    user_points
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        user_id,
        SUM(collected_items.value) AS 'user_points'
        FROM collected_items
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY SUM(collected_items.value) DESC
    ) AS T1
    GROUP BY T1.user_points
    ORDER BY T1.user_points DESC
```

Which produces results like

```
Results
user_id | user_points
2       | 61
1       | 1
```

Which is great, however I need to include the achievements, get the position of each user and also query by `users.city` (users only view leaderboards within their own city)

My ideal results would look like this:

```
Results
rank | user_id | value
```

How would I alter the above to produce the desired results? (I'm open to using PHP manipulation also)

Notes (for speed purposes):
  - There are 101 collectable items
  - There are 101 achievements
  - There will be up to 250,000 users

Comment: What should be your position? Just number from `1` to `N`, increasing consecutive?

Comment: where is the `position` field for each user? or it has to be automatically generated?

Comment: @AlmaDo Yes - just like a normal leaderboard.

Comment: @Chococroc - `position` (or `rank`) should be generated by the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use just thing like

```
SELECT
  @i:=@i+1 AS rank,
  sub.*
FROM
  (SELECT 
    user_id, 
    user_points
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        collected_items.user_id,
        SUM(collected_items.value)+SUM(achievements.value) AS user_points
        FROM 
          collected_items
            INNER JOIN achievements ON collected_items.user_id=achievements.user_id
        GROUP BY collected_items.user_id
        ORDER BY user_points DESC
    ) AS T1
    GROUP BY T1.user_points
    ORDER BY T1.user_points DESC
  ) AS sub
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) AS init
```

Comment: How would I also include the values from `achievements` table?

Comment: @ahren Oh, missed that. If you want sum from both tables, use `JOIN` by `user_id`. I've updated.

Comment: Awesome - looks pretty good! I'll accept the best answer in the morning if it all works! (it's currently 2:30am here).

Comment: I get the `Query executed successfully!` message; but no results... Any ideas?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` fails? (no corresponding rows, so `NULL`s somewhere?) I'll be able to say something certain if you'll provide sample of real data (in sqlfiddle for example)

Comment: Execute the queries from inside to outside checking if it gives you results: First T1, then sub, and then the whole query

Comment: Other thing: I think it's not necesary ORDER BY inside T1, as you will GROUP and ORDER in the sub table (and the less ORDER, the better performance, ;D)

Answer (score 1):

Refered to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861799/mysql-query-to-select-results-with-auto-increment-as-a-new-column-added-in-the-r), i would suggest:

```
SELECT 
    @s:=@s+1,
    user_id, 
    user_points
    FROM (SELECT @s:= 0),(
      SELECT 
        user_id,
        SUM(collected_items.value) AS 'user_points'
        FROM collected_items
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY SUM(collected_items.value) DESC
    ) AS T1
    GROUP BY T1.user_points
    ORDER BY T1.user_points DESC
```

Comment: How would I also include the values from `achievements` table?

Answer (score 1):

For getting additional fields, you only have to `INNER JOIN` against your `user` table again, and then, you have to order by the field users:

```
SELECT 
u.id, 
T2.*,
@i:=@i+1 AS rank

-- ... additional fields

FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT 
        user_id,
        SUM(collected_items.value) AS 'user_points'
        FROM collected_items
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY SUM(collected_items.value) DESC
    ) AS T1
    GROUP BY T1.user_points, T1.      
 ) T2
 INNER JOIN users u
 ON T2.user_id = u.id

 -- ... More inner joins to get more data...

 ORDER BY T2.user_points DESC
```